# Query returns a different result every time it is run

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

This query always returns the same amount of rows but, in a different order, every time. Why does this happen?

I have more filters to add but I can't get past this step.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @lastStatus Varchar(10)
SELECT
    [Job].[Job],
    [Job].[Part_Number],
    [Job].[Rev],
    [Job_Operation].[Description],
    [Job].[Customer_PO],
    [Job].[Customer_PO_LN],
    [Delivery].[Promised_Date],
    [Job_Operation].[Operation_Service],
    [Job].[Note_Text],
    [Job_Operation].[Status],
    [Job_Operation].[Sequence]
INTO [#tmpTbl]
FROM [PRODUCTION].[dbo].[Job_Operation]
    INNER JOIN [Job]
        ON [Job_Operation].[Job]=[Job].[Job]
    INNER JOIN [Delivery]
        ON [Job_Operation].[Job]=[Delivery].[Job]
WHERE [Job].[Status]='Complete'
ORDER BY [Job_Operation].[Job],[Job_Operation].[Sequence]
SELECT *
FROM [#tmpTbl]
DROP TABLE [#tmpTbl]
END
```

Comment: SQL makes guesses on how you want it sorted if you don't explicitly tell it how to.  Put your `ORDER BY` clause on the final `Select` statement.

Comment: Is that that just a piece of the real query?  If not why do you even have a [#tmpTbl]?

Comment: I didn't finish writing the query yet but I noticed that the result came back different every time I ran it. Now I realize that I can't order it into the temp table and it comes out the same way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the `Order By` on the `Select * From #tmpTbl`, not on the `insert`.

Comment: An ORDER BY on the first SELECT doesn't harm, though.

Comment: It's pointless sorting - it makes the query use more resources for no gain.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg It would make a difference if #temp has an index on any of those columns

Comment: No, the index would do the sorting when the data is put in.  If you sorted it opposite the index order, it would have to resort to be put into the table.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking of something that wasn't generally true.

Comment: @Blam: In this case, the table is created with SELECT INTO, so it's a heap anyway.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Exactly the index would sort and if the data came in unsorted then the index would get fragmented.   But this is a select into so it creates the table so there are not indexe.  I missed the select into part.

Answer (score 1):

You can do initials on your table and you can remove your bracket for non spaces so you can make your code shorter.

```
SELECT  j.Job,
       ,j.[Part_Number]
       ,j.Rev
       ,j_O.Description
       ,j.Customer_PO
       ,j.[Customer_PO_LN]
       ,d.[Promised_Date]
       ,j_o.[Operation_Service]
       ,j.[Note_Text],
       ,j_o.Status,
       ,j_o.Sequence
       ,j.[Customer_PO],
       ,j.[Customer_PO_LN],
       ,d.[Promised_Date],
       ,j_o.[Operation_Service],
       ,j.[Note_Text],
       ,j_o.[Status],
      [Job_Operation].[Sequence]
      INTO [#tmpTbl]
  FROM [PRODUCTION].[dbo].[Job_Operation] j_o
     INNER JOIN Job j
        ON j_o.Job = j.Job
     INNER JOIN Delivery d
        ON j_o.Job= d.Job
  WHERE j.Status='Complete'
  ORDER BY j_o.Job,j_o.Sequence
  SELECT *
    FROM [#tmpTbl]
    DROP TABLE [#tmpTbl]
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have an order by clause when you select from #tmpTbl

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM [#tmpTbl]
ORDER BY Job, Sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the order data goes into a table through a SET command (i.e. SELECT INTO) - that is determined by whether the table has a clustered index defined after it's created.

You control the order of the data when you're eventually selecting FROM that table to get your results.

```
SELECT * FROM [#tmpTbl] ORDER BY ....
```

Comment: It goes into the table in that order.